# Specify an address of my mac on host-only/nat adapter

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, vmware-fusion

I installed VMware Fusion 3 to my Mac (running 10.5.4), and I am trying use it.  But, I usually set NAT/HostOnly adapters' address to somewhere 10.0.0.0/8 range (e.g. usually I use 10.0.80.0/24 for vmnet8) for avoid collision with the future changes on real network (which falls into 192.168.0.0/16 range).

Under Linux, I can use `vmware-config.pl`, it asks me what I want, I specify, ok.
Under Windows I open the correspondent dialog, choose a correct adapter, specify, ok.
Under Mac... I don't know. How can I specify it?

To avoid misunderstands: I asks the Mac (host) side, not the virtual/guest machine side.

Answer (score 1):

There's a set of 3rd party scripts/tools to help with this on VMWare Fusion - called Tokamak.

http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8013

I haven't tried them on 3.0 yet though.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't quite follow your question....

Are you trying to define the IP ranges that your physical computer will be able to use?  That would be from your DHCP server...  Or if your manually setting your IP, that would be System Preferences --> Network --> Choose your adapter, and then advanced...

But I am unclear at what you are trying to accomplish here...